# How does one get the uncertainties for the critical exponents in Metropolis Monte Carlo for the Ising model?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, computational-physics, error-analysis, ising-model, critical-phenomena

I've recently learned the basics about simulating the Ising model with Metropolis Monte Carlo. In particular, I've seen how to evolve the system, compute the average magnetization, find the critical temperature, and use finite-size scaling to get the critical exponents.

However, I still do not understand how one can compute the uncertainties in the critical exponents. My first guess was to use the susceptibility to compute the standard deviation for the magnetization and then use these uncertainties when fitting the scaling law to get the critical exponents. This seems to not work though, especially because the magnetization diverges at the critical temperature, and hence one would get infinite uncertainty, which seems incorrect. Also, I believe the lattice sizes I chose when fitting the scaling law, the precise value of the temperature that I considered as the critical temperature, and the run-time should all contribute somehow to these uncertainties, but I can't see how to take them into account.

In short, how does one get the uncertainties for the critical exponents in Metropolis Monte Carlo for the Ising model?